# How can I perform a JOIN statement in a Hyperledger composer query?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm establishing a many to many relationship between `Participants`. I've defined this relationship in the CTO as below:

```
participant User identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String name
}

abstract concept Relationship by relationshipId {
    o String relationshipId
}

concept RelationshipChildParent extends Relationship {
    --> User child
    --> User parent
}
```

So now the next step is to fetch the related models in a single query call. If I were write this in SQL it would look like below:

```
// Get User's Children

SELECT children.*
FROM users as children

INNER JOIN relationship_parent_child as relationship
  ON children.id = relationship.child_id
INNER JOIN users as parent
  ON parent.id = relationship.parent_id

WHERE parent.id = 1
```

Interactive version : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3983ae/9

How would this be implemented in Hyperledger?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - the query language is limited see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/query-language

It is not an SQL database, rather the query is parsed and passed onto the Hyperledger Fabric world state database that is held in CouchDB